# after installing an app on snow leopard, the app is nowhere

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion, failed-installation

I recently built an application for Mac, on Mountain Lion.
After a couple of days i did a clean install on my Mac of Snow Leopard. I have a backup of the "my_app".pkg on a external hard drive, and when i run it, it proceeds with the installation normally. Or so it seems! After finishing the installation, it says "installation complete" but nothing appears in the "applications" folder, or  anywhere else.
Other applications, install correctly with no problems. 
Does it have to do that the app was made under Mountain Lion?
Thank you in advance,
Nikolas

Answer (score 0):

If you buitl the app yourself are you sure the .pkg file was correctly built? Did you test it?

You can use the pkgutil command from the command line to see what files the pkg claims to have installed on your system.

`pkgutil --pkgs` will list all the packages you have installed.

`pkgutil --files <id from earlier command>` will list the files installed by a package.

`pkgutil --pkg-info <id from earlier command>` will show you which volume you installed a package to.

To look at the actual .pkg file you can use `pkgutil --bom file.pkg`. This will extract all the bom (Bill of Materials) files into /tmp which you can then look at using `lsbom`. That will tell you what the installer wants to install.

Hopefully that is enough to get you going. If not you might need to add some extra info to the question such as the output from some of the above commands.

Comment: i used the "pkgutil --pkgs" and the pkg i used doesn't show up! i will do it all over anyway! 
Thank you

Comment: Having the same problem on another pkg.
Used the "pkgutil --pkgs-info and i see that the app seems to bee installed in the applications folder. But there isn't there...